# FFmpeg drawtext=enable'between(t,0,5)' not working

Tags: video, ffmpeg, drawtext

I'm trying to draw text on a video at different time intervals using ffmpeg. Below is my instruction:

```
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='C:\arial.ttf':text='Text1':x=5:y=20+24-max_glyph_a:fontsize=24:fontcolor=yellow:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:enable='between(t,0,20)', drawtext=fontfile='C:\arial.ttf':text='Text2':x=100:y=20+24-max_glyph_a:fontsize=24:fontcolor=yellow:enable='between(t,5,20)', drawtext=fontfile='C:\arial.ttf':text='Text3':x=200:y=20+24-max_glyph_a:fontsize=24:fontcolor=yellow:enable='between(t,10,20)'" output.mp4
```

I'm trying to draw text in a horizontal line and I want only Text1 for the first 5 seconds, and then Text2 starting from 5 seconds to 20 seconds, and Text3 starting from 10 seconds till the end.

When I do this, my first text stays for about 15 seconds and the last two show up in the last 4 seconds of the video. Is there something wrong with my instruction? Am I using the enable between correctly?

Below is the Log for ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf showinfo -vsync 0 -f null -:

```
    ffmpeg version N-91399-g9f0077cc03 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
  libavcodec     58. 20.104 / 58. 20.104
  libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'onlyVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.37.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 73 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:9], 73 kb/s, 0.20 fps, 0.20 tbr, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140] config in time_base: 1/16384, frame_rate: 1/5
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:       44 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:640x720 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:850631B2 plane_checksum:[6C2678F8 6C5D6575 C2075336] mean:[191 121 133 ] stdev:[67.7 11.8 8.5 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 17 (1845 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 16 (8 bytes)
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 640x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.20 fps, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.20.104 wrapped_avframe
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140] n:   1 pts:  81920 pts_time:5       pos:    37980 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:640x720 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:D4B0BD28 plane_checksum:[E0310E7B DC71FA0B 97BCB493] mean:[31 127 132 ] stdev:[25.6 28.9 27.1 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 17 (1845 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 16 (8 bytes)
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A speed=11.1x    
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140] n:   2 pts: 163840 pts_time:10      pos:    67732 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:640x720 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9FC30D4F plane_checksum:[1F10F7EB 45F39329 BED7821D] mean:[60 123 125 ] stdev:[61.8 11.0 5.5 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 17 (1845 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 16 (8 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140] n:   3 pts: 245760 pts_time:15      pos:   133778 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:640x720 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9F501A92 plane_checksum:[D1B4E4A7 C4CD0DFA EB7E27E2] mean:[162 129 139 ] stdev:[71.7 27.3 37.2 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 17 (1845 bytes)
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000019e4ef73140]   side data - unknown side data type 16 (8 bytes)
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:20.00 bitrate=N/A speed=21.7x    
video:2kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Share full log. Your first enable is between `(t,0,20)`.

Comment: Yes, my video is 20 seconds long. I need the first text from 0 seconds till the end. The second text from 5 seconds till the end and third from 10 seconds till the end. I updated my question with the log

Comment: The way to save ffmpeg log is add `2> file.log` at the end of the command. Share the log of `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf showinfo -vsync 0 -f null -`

Comment: Oh ok updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Need log for new cmd.

Comment: Oops..Updated it again...

Comment: Add `fps=5` filter before your first drawtext and `-r 5` before `output.mp4`

Comment: Didn't work.
I have converted a series of images to a video and now adding text on top of it. The first image and Text1 showed for the first 15 seconds, and then last few seconds Text2 and Text3 show up..

Comment: Share file. I'll check tomorrow.